# How to include @RenderPage in a WebApi Application?

Tags: razor, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Web Api application and below is the razor templates used in my code.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDr4q.png)

The _layout.cshtml page contains footer which needs to be shared across the other templates. Below is the footer to be shared across templates.

```
<p> This is footer </p>
```

I have tried using the following to share the footer but it is not rendering the page.

```
 @model SR.Services.External.Data.EmailNotificationModel
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style=\"color:#808080;font-size:8pt;font-family:Arial\">
    <p>
        Hi @Model.TargetUserName,
    </p>
    <p>
        You have been removed from community '@Model.ObjectName' by @Model.Initiator.
    </p>

    @Html.Partial("_layout.cshtml")
    @Html.Partial("~/EmailTemplates/_layout.cshtml")
    @RenderPage("~/EmailTemplates/_layout.cshtml")
    @RenderPage("_layout.cshtml")
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `@RenderPage("_layout.cshtml")` do like this, `@Html.Partial("_layout")`. But I would suggest to create a partial view for footer. For example _Footer.cshtml and just render that instead of _Layout. **_Layout.cshtml is used as a Master page**.

Comment: Other wise you can render your Layout page like this `@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml")` which is basically for Footer that I believe.

Comment: I have tried @RenderPage("_layout.cshtml") as well as @Html.Partial("_layout") bt nothings seems to working..also I have created another Shared folder where i have placed the template..but i am not able to render it also.

Comment: Will the web api application supports renderpage?

Comment: First of all you question is wrong. Web Api and Asp.Net MVC both are separate thing. You can create services in Web Api. You can't return/render view in Web Api. So if you are using Web Api and MVC both in a single project, then your question is for MVC. My above comment is for ASP.Net MVC. And you can't render/return View or page in Web Api.